# Installing Python 3.4 from source

Tags: compiling, versions, python3

I am running Xubuntu 13.10 i386 with the `python` (2.7) and `python3` (3.3) packages installed. I have downloaded and compiled the source code for Python 3.4 but the binary file is named `python`. How can I install it as `python34`? Do I change the name of the binary file and do `sudo make install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install primary versions of python with:

```
    sudo make install
```

and install secondary versions with:

```
    sudo make altinstall
```

For example, I do not have any Python installations on my system and I want to install 3 versions: 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4. I want to make 2.7 the primary installation (as `python`) and all the others as secondary (as `python3.3` and `python3.4`) installations. I would install the primary with:

```
    sudo make install
```

and install both the other versions with:

```
    sudo make altinstall
```

The produced programs would be `python` (2.7), `python3.3` (3.3) and `python3.4` (3.4)

Information from `README` file in the Python 3.4 source code directory.

Answer (score 10):

If you simply want Python 3.4 on Ubuntu and want to avoid the trouble of compiling from source, consider installing it from [Felix Krull's Python PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes)

Add the PPA

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`

Update Apt cache

`$ sudo apt-get update`

Install Python 3.4

`$ sudo apt-get install python3.4`

Comment: Since `pip` does not seem to be included by default, if you want it, just run `python3.4 -m ensurepip --upgrade`, then you can use `pip` in this way: `python3.4 -m pip install ModuleName`.