# How to install Python from the Tar.xz

Tags: python

I've downloaded the latest version of Python from their website, but I'm not exactly sure as to how to install from the tar.xz. I've extracted it to the downloads folder, but it leaves me with a folder with more folders inside. What do I do?

Comment: The XZ file is a compressed source code archive. Do you actually want to build Python from source? See [Installing Python 3.4 from source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/440427/installing-python-3-4-from-source)

Comment: I realized that after searching around a bit. I just went ahead and installed IDLE from the Software Centre.